# Junção de dois comandos sql

Tags: mysql

Ola gostaria de juntar dois comandos SQL, que são:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_os, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') FROM tbos
```

e:

```
SELECT* FROM tbos WHERE os =
```

Comment: Se possível explique/exemplifique sua dúvida, ela está bastante confusa.

Comment: O que você espera receber?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_os, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') FROM tbos) as data,
    (SELECT * FROM tbos WHERE os = '') as tudo
```

Como os dados são da mesma tabela, também assim:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(data_os, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') as data FROM tbos WHERE os = ''
```

Comment: Porque os votos contra e voto de remoção?